# Entity Framework generates wrong query for Oracle DB. How to find the actual text of the query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, oracle11g

I use Entity Framework with ODP.NET 11.2.0.2.0, on Oracle 11g Express.

I make certain authorization on fetched rows. Rules are written in C# and are used in `.Where` clause of my results, that is (simplified example):

```
var results = Source.Where(selectionPredicate);
var filtered = results.Where(authPredicate);
return filtered.ToList(); <-- exception thrown
```

It worked quite well, all the rules where translated to SQL. At one point I had to change one of the rules from

```
(x, y) => x.Declarations.Any(d => d.Employment.Id == y)
```

to

```
(x, y) => x.Declarations.Any(d => d.Employment.Substitutions.Any())
```

It is again a simplified example. `x` is an object I would like to fetch, `y` is some constant parameter. `Declarations`, `Declarations.Employment` and `Declarations.Employment.Substitutions` are all navigation properties over some foreign keys. The code actually compiles, so these fields are there etc. I know these are massive joins but I don't care at the moment. All of the properties are loaded with `Load` method.

Please notice, that only the longest navigation property does not work, filtering on `Declarations.Employment.Id` makes no problems.

The problem is with the error itself. It's `System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException` with ORA error `{"ORA-00904: \"Extent1\".\"ID\": invalid identifier"}`.

While we do not rely on hand-written SQL, I believe there is a problem with translation process. I would like to see the actual query, for example to know which table is this `Extent1` (all my relations HAVE `ID` field...).

When I try to view `ObjectSet.ToTraceString()` it only shows a basic fetch query with no `WHERE` clause, so I don't believe it includes the filtering predicates. The query itself is correct.

Usually I retrieved queries from `v$sql` relation, but it won't contain wrong queries.

How can I find what query is actually being sent to Oracle? Maybe there are tools working as proxies for database?

Any suggestions why such a translations fails?

Comment: I'm not sure about Oracle, but SQL Server has a SQL Profiler, which can be useful.

Comment: Well, our code depends heavily on Oracle, so I will not be able to test it. Apart from that, I think it's the ODP.NET component, provided by Oracle, that makes the mess.